# Underscore's bindAll: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="menu"></div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            'click #menu': 'insideMenuHandler'
        },
    //for event click
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'insideMenuHandler', 'outsideMenuHandler');
        },

        render: function() {
            // Both <body> and <html> for paranoia.
            $('body, html').on('click', this.outsideMenuHandler);
            // ...
            return this;
        },

        remove: function() {
            // Clean up after ourselves.
            $('body, html').off('click', this.outsideMenuHandler);
            // ...
        },

        // ...
        outsideMenuHandler: function(e) {
            // ...
            return false;
        }
    });

    var v=new myView({el: '#view-goes-here'});
    v.render();

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hey i am new to backbone.js and not understanding what is wrong in the code below, where do i change my code to make it working? Is there a problem with the bind function or something else is going wrong?

Comment: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined... on initialize line.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling `_.bindAll` in the line

```
 _.bindAll(this, 'insideMenuHandler', 'outsideMenuHandler');
```

but you don't have any function with name `insideMenuHandler` in the `view`.

Comment: I just defined that function but i am getting an error in that line Unexpected identifier.

Comment: You might have forgotten comma after the ending curly brace of the previous function where you defined the `insideMenuHandler` function. Not sure but.

Comment: Yes i missed the comma, but still couldn't see any output on the browser.

Comment: Have you added any content in the `menu` div ? And whats the code in the `insideMenuHandler` method ?

Comment: Yes I added few items in menu and there is just an alert box in insideMenuHandler.

Comment: whatever `el` is being specified with `{el: '#view-goes-here'}` has to be present in the `DOM`. So you add one div in html with that ID and give it a try.

Comment: <div id="menu">
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Mauricii</li>
<li>Periher</li>
<li>Tyrio</li>
<li>Quicumque</li>
</div>  I added this in the div.